# Google Web Services Pricing?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am looking at the Google Web Services pricing on:

https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/

If I look at:

Google Maps Directions API
Google Maps Geocoding API

They say on the web page Free up to 2,500 requests per day.

This would be free if I use both or is it for an aggregate total of all these one listed.

Google Maps Directions API = 2000
Google Maps Geocoding API = 500

So if I did another query on either then I would be charged. Or can I go to 2500 on each of the items before I am charged?

Google Maps Directions API
Google Maps Distance Matrix API 4
Google Maps Elevation API
Google Maps Geocoding API
Google Maps Geolocation API
Google Maps Roads API
Google Maps Time Zone API

Thanks,

Ward.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines. If you have questions about vendor pricing for various products, contact that vendor directly via their web site or email.

Comment: Someone just asked this like 3 hours ago. Was that you?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Actually it was not me that asked previously.

Answer (score 0):

Each web service has its own usage quota. You can execute up to 2.5K daily requests free of charge for each one.

For further details please refer to the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/usage-limits

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/usage-limits

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/usage-limits

Also, note that distance matrix usage is measured in number of elements and not in number of requests. The number of elements is a number of origins times a number of destinations in your request. So, sending for example 5 origins and 5 destinations (25 elements) in each distance matrix request you will be able to execute only 100 daily requests free of charge.